# Error during mongo startup

Tags: mongodb

When I type **mongo** on command prompt than output like

~$ `mongo`

`MongoDB shell version: 2.2.3`

`connecting to: test`

But when I type **mongo 127.0.0.1:28017/stu1**

output :-

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.3

connecting to: 127.0.0.1:28017/stu1

Mon Mar 10 16:56:01 DBClientCursor::init call() failed

Mon Mar 10 16:56:01 Error: Error during mongo startup. :: caused by :: 10276 

DBClientBase::findN: transport error: 127.0.0.1:28017 ns: admin.$cmd query: { whatsmyuri: 1 } src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:93


exception: connect failed
```

OS :- ubuntu 12.04

So please help me to solve this error.

Comment: Can you try it with `--verbose` flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`28017` is the default port for the HTTP admin interface, so if your config is allowing HTTP, you should use a web browser to access it `http://127.0.0.1:28017/`
You're trying to use mongo shell to access HTTP service.

Answer (score 0):

To have access to the database using HTTP protocol then use **~$ mongod --rest** to start the db. Now call http://127.0.0.1:28017/stu1/coll_name in the web browser which list all the documents in your collection.